# Mysql count values in multiple columns if minus then 1

Tags: php, mysql, operators

Hi i have a database and i try to make an count where i can multiple  the values and the to make an count from them.

```
    ----------------------
    |id | name|parts|date|
    ---------------------
    |1  |abc  | 2   |2016|
    ---------------------
    |1  |bcd  | 3   |2017|
    ---------------------
    |1  |cde  | -5  |2018|
    ----------------------
```

And what i need is :

```
    -----------
    |id |count|
    -----------
    |1  |  6  | 
    -----------
```

As i said if i have an minu(-) then is 1 doesn't matter if is -3 or -5 is eqal with 1;  **2+3+1 = 6;**

Comment: I don't understand your question is, can you explain it ?

Comment: i want to make an count where id = 1 but with value for example i have there value 2,3,-5 i want o make someting like 2+3 =5 and if i have a value with - minus that value will be eqal with 1 and i will have 2+3+1 = 6

Comment: Do you only want to select id = 1 or no? or you want to select by id where id is can be anything?

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya just only by id. thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id, SUM(IF(parts < 0, 1, parts)) AS `count`

FROM table

GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `id`, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (`parts` < 0) THEN 1 ELSE `parts` END) AS Count 
FROM `TableName` 
GROUP BY `id`
```

The `SUM()` function returns the total sum of a numeric column.

The `CASE` function lets you evaluate conditions and return a value when the first condition is met (like an `IF-THEN-ELSE` statement)

Answer (score -1):

After read it several times, I think this is what you want to achieve.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    SUM(IF(parts < 0, 1, parts)) AS count
FROM 
    products
GROUP BY
    id
```